# Что делает return 1 в конце функции и почему он важен?

Tags: python, рекурсия, return

Есть код - обычное возведение в степень, но через рекурсию.

Не совсем понимаю, зачем нужен return 1 в конце функции. Я так понимаю функции просто что-то надо вывести если условие не выполнено?

Но почему она просто не закончится? И почему используется не банальный return 0?

```
def power(a, n):
    if n != 0:
        return a * power(a, n-1)
    return 1


print(power(float(input()), float(input())))
```

Comment: Думаете, `power(1, 0)` должен выводить именно 0?

Comment: Разберитесь, пожалуйста, в **логике** кода, а потом уже задавайте вопрос про функции. Если Вы считаете, что `a**0` == `0`, то с вопросами кода можно пока что обождать.

Comment: Тут проблема не в а**0 а в том чтоб закончить рекурсию когда доберемся до хвоста. Без ретурн 1 ответ будет также правильный, если убрать и иф. Но рекурсия не остановится.

Answer (score 2):

Это рекурсивная функция. Она вызывает сама себя для вычисления степени, уменьшая при этом степень на 1. При степени равной 0, возвращает 1. Потому что любое число в степени 0 равно 1.

Answer (score 1):

return прерывает выполнение функции, возвращая что-либо. В данном примере, если условие `if n != 0` выполняется, то функция возвращает `a * power(a, n-1)` и прерывается, если нет, то возвращает единицу. То есть приведенная функция эквивалентна данной:

```
def power(a, n):
    if n != 0:
        return a * power(a, n-1)
    else:
        return 1
```